# R: Is there a way to subset a file while reading

Tags: r, csv

I have a huge `.csv` file, its size is ~ 1.4G and reading with `read.csv` takes time. There are several variables in that file and all i want is to extract data for few variables in a certain column.

For example, suppose `ABC.csv` is my file and it looks something like this:

```
   ABC.csv
     Date       Variables   Val
   2017-11-01   X           23  
   2017-11-01   A           2
   2017-11-01   B           0.5
   ............................
   2017-11-02   X           20
   2017-11-02   C           40
   ............................
   2017-11-03   D           33
   2017-11-03   X           22   
   ............................
   ............................
```

So , here the variable of interest is `X` and while reading this file i want the `df$Variables` to be scanned reading only the rows with `X` string in this column.  So that my new data from will look something like this:

```
 > df 
  Date    Variables   Val
2017-11-01    X       23
2017-11-02    X       20
.........................
.........................
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It may be better to check `rxImport` from `RevoScaleR`.  It have options for selecting both rows and columns

Comment: Why are you not using `fread`?

Comment: Also keep an eye here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/583

Comment: Thank you @Akrun  i will go through your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelChirico i will go through `fread` as well.

Comment: I have used it and the data size is not a matter as it doesn't store in memory

Comment: 1.4 GB is small. Just read it with fread and subset. That should complete pretty instantaneous.

Comment: If 1.4Gb is too much for your RAM to handle, you need to buy more RAM or find a remote machine to use. 1.4Gb should be next to nothing for a machine meant to do data work.

Comment: I am working on the supercomputer so 1.4 G is not too much for the RAM, but I have several files of the similar size and need to do the same task. And writing and checking the script to get the output of interest, I have to load and unload the files several times, so the motive was to save time while repeating these cumbersome steps. @MichaelChirico

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `LaF` package, it allows to read very large textfiles in blocks, so you don't have to read the entire file into memory.

```
library(LaF)

data_model <- detect_dm_csv("yourFile.csv", skip = 1) # detects the file structure
dat <- laf_open(data_model) # opens connection to the file

block_list <- lapply(seq(1,100000,1000), function(row_num){
    goto(dat, row_num)
    data_block <- next_block(dat, nrows = 1000) # reads data blocks of 1000 rows
    data_block <- data_block[data_block$Variables == "X",]
    return(data_block)
})
your_df <- do.call("rbind", block_list)
```

Admittedly, the package sometimes feels a bit bulky and in some situations I had to find small hacks to get my results (you might have to adapt my solution for your data). Nevertheless, I found it a immensely useful solution for dealing with files that exceeded my RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if doing this works. It worked for my code but I am not sure whether it is first reading in the entire data and then subsetting or is it only reading the part of the file where `Variables == 'X'`.

```
temp <- fread('dat.csv')[Variables == 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that most of the time you can probably just read in the entire file, and then subset within R:

```
df <- read.csv(file="path/to/your/file.csv", header=TRUE)
df.x <- df[df$Variables=='x', ]
```

R operates completely in memory, so an exception to what I said above might occur if you have a file whose total size is so massive that it cannot fit into memory, but for some reason the subset of interest can.

Comment: That is what i was doing, but I want to save time while reading the huge size file.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire Then `fread` seems like a good option.  Write only the lines you actually want.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire But I'm not sure how much actual time you would save.  In any case, you need to scan the entire file, even if you discard certain rows in the process.  But yes, you may save memory.

Comment: This is where an `awk` solution might be preferable. This is a fixed-width format file and I'm pretty sure `awk` an do logical operations on character positions.