# Read only rows of a large file with row names specified in vector - R

Tags: r, subset, large-files, read.table

I am trying to do a rather simple task in R - from a large .tsv file (4GB) that I wasn't able to read into memory I would like to read only rows with row names defined in a list. Row names are defined in the first column of the large file called "PMID" and I have a list of PMIDs that I would like to extract from the large file.

I am quite new to R and even though I can use the function match or %in% on a loaded file in R I have trouble to do the same by reading the .tsv file. I used read.table to load the large file but got an error "cannot allocate vector of size 250.0 Mb".

The large .tsv file is structured as follows:

```
"PMID"  "au_order"  "lastname"  "firstname" "year"  "journal    type"   "city"  "state" "country"   "lat"   "lon"   "fips"
26151967    1   Lau Ying    2016    J Hum Lact  EDU Queenstown, Singapore   -   Singapore   1.299   103.787 NULL
26151969    2   Htun    Tha Pyai    2016    J Hum Lact  EDU Queenstown, Singapore   -   Singapore   1.299   103.787 NULL
26151965    3   Lim Peng Im 2016    J Hum Lact  EDU-HOS Queenstown, Singapore   -   Singapore   1.299   103.787 NULL

My_vector = c("26151969","26151965")
```

Output:

```
"PMID"  "au_order"  "lastname"  "firstname" "year"  "journal type" "city"   "state" "country"   "lat"   "lon"   "fips"
26151969    2   Htun    Tha Pyai    2016    J Hum Lact  EDU Queenstown, Singapore   -   Singapore   1.299   103.787 NULL
26151965    3   Lim Peng Im 2016    J Hum Lact  EDU-HOS Queenstown, Singapore   -   Singapore   1.299   103.787 NULL
```

I would be very thankful for any help and I apologize if this is a duplicate but even after long search I could not find any answer that I would understand so far.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172355/r-is-there-a-way-to-subset-a-file-while-reading

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes